# How can I do a phone call with Skype?

Tags: php, html, voip, skype

I'm trying to make a button with funcionality of phone calling using Skype (not Skype For Business). I've bought a prepaid which allows me to make phone calls. For Skype-Skype call I'm using command:

```
<a href="skype:useremail@email.com?call" class="generate-call btn btn-success" >Call</a>
```

Is it possible to make a Skype phone call with similar way? Or I need different construction?

Comment: you have to configure your browser or your system to recognize `skype:` and to choose your app (skype) to run with

Comment: The code I've pasted works, it launches Skype correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
<a href="callto://+[the number]">Link will initiate Skype to call my number!</a>

<a href="skype:[the number]?call">Link will initiate Skype
   to call my Skype username!</a>
```

Comment: Do I need to type number like +48123456789 (+48 means area code of Poland) or just a 123456789?

Comment: <a href="callto:+48123456789" class="generate-call btn btn-success" >Call</a>  Works perfectly ;)